# Completely display labels on barchart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm plotting an horizontal barchart with matplotlib, with labels on the y axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["Something really long here", "normal"]
values = [10, 5]
plt.barh(range(len(labels)), values)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(labels)) + .5, labels, rotation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

However I'm not satisfied with the result: plt.show() does not display the labels completely, like this:
[image]

Is there any option to achieve that (i.e. not having only "y long here" displayed) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [tight_layout](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) function to prevent the window to cut the labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["Something really long here", "normal"]
values = [10, 5]
plt.barh(range(len(labels)), values)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(labels)) + .5, labels, rotation='horizontal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]